# Unable to resolve dependency for graph view-4.2.2 from mavenCentral

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-graphview

the error i'm getting is:

> error: Unable to resolve dependency for 'app@debug/compileClasspath':Could not resolve com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2

I'm trying to integrate graphview into my android application and am following the  documentation provided on their site. During gradlesync, it repeatedly tries to download the graphview pom file from the mentioned repositories but is failing and is trying the same thing again and again thus my gradlesync is taking forever.
Can anyone help with this? If there's any doubt in what i've mentioned please ask and help me solve this issue! Thanks!

I have included mavenCentral in buildscript  repositories as well as allprojects repositories. In the dependencies section I have added the required dependency for graphview 4.2.2. Android Studio still can't perform a successful gradle sync.

```
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
```

Comment: Share the project build.gradle and app/build.gradle